# Subspace $V\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ contains vectors $\underline v_1,...,\underline v_k$ is this just the $span \{\underline v_1,...,\underline v_k \}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Basically the title, if a subspace $V\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ and $V$ contains vectors $\underline v_1,...,\underline v_k$. Is this subspace the $span \{\underline v_1,...,\underline v_k \}$. Is $V$ a larger subspace? What can $V$ be written as?

Thanks

Comment: $span\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k\}$ will be a vector space, $\subseteq V$. If every vector in $V$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1,\cdots v_k$, then the vector space will equal $V$. If we can find a vector in $V$ that is independent of $v_1,\cdots,v_k$, then $V$ is clearly a superset.

Comment: Without knowing what the subspace $V$ is and what the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are, we can't say for sure whether the span is a proper subset of $V$ or equal to $V$, though it has to be one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. The vectors $(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)$ are contained in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but they do not span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify $V$ with the $span(v_1,...,v_k)$ if $V$ is a $linear$ subspace.

If $V$ contains $v_1,...,v_k$, and $V$ is a linear subspaace of $\mathbb{R^n}$, then it must contain every linear combination of this vectors, because a linear subspace is closed under moltiplication for scalar and sum by definition.
So we can write $V$ as $V= \{ \sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i, \forall i=1..k, a_i \in \mathbb{R^n} \}$, which is of course the definition of span of a subset of $k$-vectors.

Comment: Okay yeah $V$ is linear i didnt say that :P. So would this be enough to prove the $span \{\underline v_1,...,\underline v_k \} \subseteq V$, would this be the same as saying that $span \{\underline v_1,...,\underline v_k \} = V$ as the definition of a span is the same?